# firefox no WebGL

Tags: firefox, 22.04, webgl

because of slow cold start and bad performances, I installed Firefox in .deb mode via Firefox PPA instead of snap on Ubuntu 22. The problem here is WebGL which is not working.

When I start Firefox, I have this error :

```
$ firefox
[GFX1-]: No GPUs detected via PCI
[GFX1-]: glxtest: process failed (received signal 11)
```

my laptop haves a Nvidia PRIME GPU :

```
$ lspci
...
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
...
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
...
```

Thank by advance for your answers